# How to sample from different datasets such that they have similar distributions?

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, dataset

I have data from multiple datasets with the boxplot given below

[image]

In the above figure, I have data from 7 different datasets. I am looking for a sampling strategy without replacement such that samples from each dataset have similar distribution (probably they have the same mean and standard deviation or some other sort of similarity). It should be fine if the strategy loses a number of data from multiple sites.

Comment: You could create a proxy distribution of those distributions and then sample randomly from all distribution based on the probability they belong to the proxy distribution.

Comment: Why not sample from the data? If your data for group 1 are $\{1,2,3,9,4,5,7,8,3,1\}$, then draw from the data with replacement to get a data set like $\{1,2,7,9,4,7,1\}$. You can have whatever sample size you want, either larger or smaller than the original data set.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the sampling strategy should sample without replacement.

Comment: Why without replacement?

Comment: Downstream analysis of the data requires that samples shouldn't be repetitive.

Comment: Just to clarify: Are these 7 datasets say $D_1, D_2, \dots, D_7$ measuring the same quantity? Are you expected to create 7 new datasets $D_1^*, D_2^*, \dots, D_7^*$ such that $\hat{\mu}_{D_1^*} = \hat{\mu}_{D_2^*} = \dots = \hat{\mu}_{D_7^*}$ and similarly $\hat{\sigma}_{D_1^*} = \dots = \hat{\sigma}_{D_7^*}$? Also by looking at these boxplots datasets 3,4 and 5 don't seem like they have a great overlap with datasets 1 and 6; the majority of the mass of the 7 new datasets has to be in the common support of the 7 original datasets by definition and that doesn't seem to be wide...

Comment: I suspect [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) is a potential avenue here but it will be messy.

Comment: They don't have to be exactly equal, some margin of error should be ok there. I looked at that, but yes would be messy.

Answer (score 1):

Try covariate balancing, i.e. learn weights $w_i, u_j$ such that $\sum_{i} w_i X_i = \sum_j u_j Y_j$ and $\sum_{i} w_i X_i^2 = \sum_j u_j Y_j^2$ for two of the datasets $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_j\}$, then sample using propabilities proportional to the weight. This should balance the mean and the variance at least.

Comment: How do you propose to learn these weights?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy That's a good question. I am thinking of trying least squares solvers. Suppose all weights for $u_i  = 1/n$ then try to learn $w$'s such that $w^{\top}X = \bar{Y}$ and $w^{\top}X = \bar{Y^2}$ using least squares?

Comment: I am applying the balancing score idea in causal inference to a non-causal problem here. This might be helpful: https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/journalclub/propensity.pdf

Comment: ... Not a totally bad proposition but given that the OP says "without replacement" it kind of kills the notion of using a weighted sample indirectly.

Comment: Well in that case, for each dataset we can generate a pseudo dataset where the proportion of each datapoint matches the probability induced by the weight. Now we have an urn with $N$ balls where there are $n_i$ of color $x_i$ with $w_i = n_i/N$. Then sample without replacement?